# Uncaught Reference Error: gapi is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-sheets-api, require, uncaught-reference-error

So I'm trying to experiment with accessing my google spreadsheet using JS, and I'm a beginner, and probably way in over my head, but I need help
So I have this script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Google Sheets API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Google Sheets API Quickstart</p>

    <!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
    <button id="authorize_button" style="display: none;">Authorize</button>
    <button id="signout_button" style="display: none;">Sign Out</button>

    <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      // Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
      var CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID';
      var API_KEY = 'API_KEY';

      // Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
      var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4"];

      // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
      // included, separated by spaces.
      var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly";

      var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize_button');
      var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout_button');

      /**
       *  On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
       */
      function handleClientLoad() {
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
      }

      /**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          apiKey: API_KEY,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        }, function(error) {
          appendPre(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
        });
      }

      /**
       *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
       *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
       */
      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
          listMajors();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }

      /**
       *  Sign in the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleAuthClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
      }

      /**
       *  Sign out the user upon button click.
       */
      function handleSignoutClick(event) {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
      }

      /**
       * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
       * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
       *
       * @param {string} message Text to be placed in pre element.
       */
      function appendPre(message) {
        var pre = document.getElementById('content');
        var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
        pre.appendChild(textContent);
      }

      /**
       * Print the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
       * https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
       */
      function listMajors() {
        gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
          spreadsheetId: 'ID',
          range: 'Class Data!A1:A1',
        }).then(function(response) {
          var range = response.result;
          console.log(range);
          if (range.values.length > 0) {
            appendPre('Name, Major:');
            for (i = 0; i < range.values.length; i++) {
              var row = range.values[i];
              // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
              appendPre(row[0] + ', ' + row[4]);
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No data found.');
          }
        }, function(response) {
          appendPre('Error: ' + response.result.error.message);
        });
      }
listMajors()
    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
      onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
      onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basically what I'm trying to do here is to access my spreadsheet and print the first column of the first row as a range of (A1 to A1), and my function listMajors() is supposed to do it, but I'm struck with this error

```
"<a class='gotoLine' href='#144:9'>144:9</a> Uncaught ReferenceError: gapi is not defined"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `listMajors` before the script tag with `src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"` is actually loaded. The reason for that is that `gapi` is being set up asynchronously.

In this case, `listMajors()` at the end of the script tag is being executed before `gapi` is even loaded. You are already calling it in the `updateSigninStatus` so I'm guessing that it will be properly called if you remove that line.

Note that I haven't looked into the code in that function (and you should probably make another question if that doesn't work and you can't figure why).

Answer (score 0):

`gapi` needs to be loaded and you need to be authenticated, before your code can work. So the earliest place in your code, where you could call `listMajors()` would be in `handleAuthClick()`:

```
function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn().then(function() {
        listMajors();
    }, function() {
        appendPre('Error while authenticating');
    });
}
```

Don't forget to remove the two(!) existing calls to `listMajors()` from your code.